# jq: How to select within a nested array

Tags: json, select, jq

I am trying to select a sub-set of an object's children in `jq` while keeping the outer object.

Take the example input:

```
{
  "head": "master",
  "hash": "ba2054c38ec68b73926acb24cd0bad61177a03d4",
  "upstream": "origin/master",
  "ahead": 1,
  "behind": 0,
  "changes": [
    {
      "name": "exe/each-package",
      "status": "updated_in_index",
      "work_tree_status": "modified",
      "index_status": "unmodified"
    },
    {
      "name": "exe/find-package",
      "status": "not_updated",
      "work_tree_status": "unmodified",
      "index_status": "modified"
    },
    {
      "name": "lib/tools/tool_support.rb",
      "status": "not_updated",
      "work_tree_status": "unmodified",
      "index_status": "modified"
    },
    {
      "name": "curses.txt",
      "status": "untracked",
      "work_tree_status": "untracked",
      "index_status": "untracked"
    },
    {
      "name": "exe/fat-stat",
      "status": "untracked",
      "work_tree_status": "untracked",
      "index_status": "untracked"
    },
    {
      "name": "exe/prefix-each-with",
      "status": "untracked",
      "work_tree_status": "untracked",
      "index_status": "untracked"
    },
    {
      "name": "notes.txt",
      "status": "untracked",
      "work_tree_status": "untracked",
      "index_status": "untracked"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the expected output where I have removed a subset of the `changes` member:

```
{
  "head": "master",
  "hash": "ba2054c38ec68b73926acb24cd0bad61177a03d4",
  "upstream": "origin/master",
  "ahead": 1,
  "behind": 0,
  "changes": [
    {
      "name": "exe/each-package",
      "status": "updated_in_index",
      "work_tree_status": "modified",
      "index_status": "unmodified"
    },
    {
      "name": "exe/find-package",
      "status": "not_updated",
      "work_tree_status": "unmodified",
      "index_status": "modified"
    },
    {
      "name": "lib/tools/tool_support.rb",
      "status": "not_updated",
      "work_tree_status": "unmodified",
      "index_status": "modified"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was able to do it like the following. But I suspect there is a more succinct way to filter the innards of a nested array, perhaps removing the duplication.

```
jq '. + {changes: [.changes[] | select(.status != "untracked")]}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More succinct can be achieved by:

```
.changes |= map(select(.status != "untracked"))
```

Comment: Gorgeous! I love it.